# docker container as gateway between two docker bridges

Tags: docker

I am trying to simulate production network with docker.

I have two docker bridges, `bridge1` and `bridge2`.

I want to put another docker container as `router gateway` between them.

Not sure about following commands, want to do like this:

```
Router: (172.17.0.2)
iptables --table nat --append POSTROUTING --out-interface eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -I FORWARD -s 192.168.9.0/24 -d 192.168.8.0/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD -s 192.168.8.0/24 -d 192.168.9.0/24 -j ACCEPT
```

---

```
Bridge1:
ip route add 192.168.9.0/24 via 172.17.0.2 dev eth0
```

---

```
Bridge2:
ip route add 192.168.8.0/24 via 172.17.0.2 dev eth0
```

are those above commands correct? but how can I add those iptables rules, some how I cannot change them.

Answer (score 3):

You need `--cap-add=NET_ADMIN` to be able to run `iptables` command in docker containers.

Read: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-and-linux-capabilities