# Use docker container as network gateway

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

I want to configure a gateway to connect two containers. Below is an example compose file that creates three containers - a test_client, a test_server and a proxy. The proxy server should act as the default gateway for all traffic to the test_server from the test_client. I am using compose file format v2 as IPAM gateway configurations are not supported in v3.

```
version: "2"
services:
  proxy:
    build: .
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
    expose:
      - 8080
      - 80
      - 443
    networks:
      client_network:
          ipv4_address: '192.168.0.5'
      server_network: null
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
  test_server:
    build: ./test_server
    expose:
      - 8000
    networks:
      - server_network
  test_client:
    build: ./test_client
    networks:
      - client_network
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true

networks:
  client_network:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: "192.168.0.0/24"
          gateway: "192.168.0.5"
  server_network:
    driver: bridge
```

When I run `docker-compose up`, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: for 28e458cec9ac_network_proxy_1  b'user specified IP address is supported only when connecting to networks with user configured subnets'
```

I've read the following resources:

[SO: docker container as gateway between two docker bridges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45695927/docker-container-as-gateway-between-two-docker-bridges)
[Docker forums](https://forums.docker.com/t/setting-default-gateway-to-a-container/17420)

But they don't seem to help me answer how I get this setup. I'm not committed to any particular networking structure - the only thing I want is to configure something where one container acts as a network-level gateway between two other containers.

Comment: Alright, I'm really not sure about this, but considering that the only network in your docker-compose file is "user-specified" in the sense that you do define it explicitly, could your problem be that you are using a subnet that is already used by your host's networking? Maybe switch to `192.168.5.0/24` and see if it changes anything?

Comment: Had the same problem. Your docker-compose file looks fine to me. I guess, you tried creating the stuff without the subnet config and now docker won't update the network configuration to the one with a subnet specified... check with `docker network inspect client_network`. If that's the case, DO NOT remove it with "docker network rm" or you would break lots of stuff (just found out the hard way), seems like you should remove the networks via `docker-compose down`... See: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/5745#issuecomment-370031631 (haven't tested this, chose the wrong way)

Answer (score 10):

Unfortunately this use-case isn't really supported by bridge networks (or any other kind of docker network). The problem is that bridge networks use your host machine as the gateway. It does this by creating a virtual interface for your host on the bridge network and doing some host configuration to implement the necessary routing. The `gateway` option only configures what IP address will be assigned to this virtual interface.

This doesn't seem to be well documented, I think it's considered an implementation detail of docker networking. I found it out from a couple of forum posts: [source 1](https://forums.docker.com/t/setting-default-gateway-to-a-container/17420/2), [source 2](https://forums.docker.com/t/new-user-set-default-gateway-of-container-to-other-machine-in-lan/35066).

Edit: Here's my working docker-compose file. This has two private networks, each with it's own gateway, ie `alice <-> moon <-> sun <-> bob`. The magic is in the `ip` and `iptables` commands inside the `command:` block run by each container. Ignore the `tail -f /dev/null`, it's just a command that will never finish which means the container stays running until you kill it.

```
version: "3.3"

services:

  alice:
    image: ubuntu-with-tools
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
    hostname: alice
    networks:
      moon-internal:
        ipv4_address: 172.28.0.3
    command: >-
      sh -c "ip route del default &&
      ip route add default via 172.28.0.2 &&
      tail -f /dev/null"

  moon:
    image: ubuntu-with-tools
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
    hostname: moon
    networks:
      moon-internal:
        ipv4_address: 172.28.0.2
      internet:
        ipv4_address: 172.30.0.2
    command: >-
      sh -c "iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE &&
      iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE &&
      iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -j ACCEPT &&
      iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -j ACCEPT &&
      ip route add 172.29.0.0/16 via 172.30.0.4 &&
      tail -f /dev/null"


  sun:
    image: ubuntu-with-tools
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
    hostname: sun
    networks:
      sun-internal:
        ipv4_address: 172.29.0.4
      internet:
        ipv4_address: 172.30.0.4
    command: >-
      sh -c "iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE &&
      iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE &&
      iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -j ACCEPT &&
      iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -j ACCEPT &&
      ip route add 172.28.0.0/16 via 172.30.0.2 &&
      tail -f /dev/null"

  bob:
    image: ubuntu-with-tools
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
    hostname: bob
    networks:
      sun-internal:
        ipv4_address: 172.29.0.5
    command: >-
      sh -c "ip route del default &&
      ip route add default via 172.29.0.4 &&
      tail -f /dev/null"


networks:
  moon-internal:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.28.0.0/16
  sun-internal:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.29.0.0/16
  internet:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.30.0.0/16
```

To try it out run `docker exec -it ipsec-playground_bob_1 tcpdump` and `docker exec -it ipsec-playground_alice_1 ping 172.29.0.5`. You should see pings from alice reaching bob.

`ubuntu-with-tools` is a simple ubuntu image with some things that I wanted installed, here's the Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get update \
    && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y iproute2 inetutils-ping curl host mtr-tiny tcpdump iptables \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Comment: This looks awesome! Thanks. I was working on this a while a go, but hopefully will get a chance to test it out soon. I'll mark it as the accepted answer once I've given it a go.

Comment: It doesn't work with "internal" networks, why ?

Comment: @Taknok I spent much time trying to answer the same question and came up empty handed

Comment: Oh weird, it's probably because docker uses iptables internally to implement internal networks. Whatever it does is probably incompatible with this setup. If so then to get it working you'll need different commands.